# Automatic Lock Form2 Positioning in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder

My application is using two forms. When I click a panel in main form, the Form2 should showing up. There're a few pixels distance between the Main Form and Form2.

Now what I need is when I move the Main Form to anywhere, then Form2 moves where ever Main Form goes. I mean I need Form2 to be lock on Main Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the MainForm override the virtual `WndProc()` method to reposition Form2 as needed relative to the MainForm's current position whenever a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` or `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message is received.

```
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
...
protected:
   void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
...
};
```

```
...
#include "Form2.h"

...

void __fastcall TMainForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
    switch (Message.Msg)
    {
        case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
        case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
        {
            if ((Form2) && (Form2->Visible))
            {
                Form2->Left = ...; // such as this->Left
                Form2->Top = ...; // such as this->Top + this->Height
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remy: it's not working. Form2 remains unchanged in its position and did not move at all. I put the `void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);` under `private:` section of unit.h .

Comment: Works fine for me when I use it exactly as I have shown.

Comment: ok, but can you tell me, are those the only codes that you're using in main form? and what's about the code in form2?  thank you.

Comment: Still doen't working. Can you give me the example of full working code inside the both form ? I need your help, please.

Comment: I gave you the full code needed. There is no code needed in Form2.